# Forge Color Display Error

Tags: colors, display, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, forge

I have set up the color scheme to identify the different system of the building services in Revit and Navisworks. When I uploaded to the forge viewer, the colors were shown correctly at the beginning. However, when I zoomed in, some of the colors were disappeared. Did anyone have this problem? How could the problem be solved?
Thank you.

Forge Display Error:
[image: Forge Display Error]

Zooming Lo01
[image: Zooming Lo01]

Answer (score 0):

Apologizing for any inconvenience caused, this might be a known issue of our model extraction service for the Revit, it has been logged as `REVIT-120524` in our case system to let our dev team to allocate time to investigate it. You can send this id to `forge.help@autodesk.com` to inquire updates in the future.

BTW, the reason caused this issue I discovered is there are many MEP system type, and they have owned different colored material, fittings will take materail color from the first system type from corrosponding MEP systems. Currently, there is not formal solution to avoid this. We apology for this again. Fortunately, there is a workaroud you could try:

1. Split your MEP models into servral RVT files that contain single pipe system, duct system and others.
2. Upload them to the Forge for translation seperately.
3. Load translated models via the Forge Viewer.

Hope it helps.

**This workaround is working on my live projects now, but might not suite for you. And it's not the formal solution, you might have to use it at your own risk.**